# classification for concordance index

Tags: classification, survival, concordance

In [this paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0084483) (and in most of the others I found), the authors want to find a continuous predictor that maximizes the **concordance index**. I would like to have a **binary classifier** instead that stratifies that patients into two groups such that the concordance is maximized (i.e. the nu in the paper is a classifier).

Is anyone aware of such an approach/paper?

Comment: Is thresholding the continuous predictor not an option?

Comment: If there are several covariables in the predictor, it will become hard to find reasonable thresholds. So I would prefer to directly optimize what I am looking for (not indirectly via regression).